# I want to update table records in sql 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I want to write this query by using case statement in `sql 2014` i want to udate  500 record on base of `pk_id`

```
     UPDATE [dbo].[SRules]
     SET 
     [Text] = 'abc'
     ,[CreatedOn] = '2021-06-06'
     ,[CreatedBy] = 2
     ,[UpdatedOn] = '2021-06-06'
     ,[UpdatedBy] = 2
     ,[English_Text] = N' आवेदक 10 वीं कक्षा उत्तीर्ण हो'
     WHERE Pk_Id=1

     UPDATE [dbo].[Scheme_Eligibility_Rules]
     SET 
     Text = 'zxc'
     ,CreatedOn = '2021-06-06'
     ,CreatedBy = 2
     ,UpdatedOn = '2021-06-06'
     ,UpdatedBy = 2
     ,English_Text = N'आवेदक अनुसूचित जाति से सम्बन्धित हो`
     WHERE Pk_Id=2
```

Comment: every one of the 500 rows will have different `[Text]` value ?

Comment: YES EVERY ROW HAVE DIFFERENT TEXT VALUES

Comment: put it in temp table and join to your table and update